# AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'oov_token' in Keras

Tags: python, nlp, keras, pickle, tokenize

I am trying to encode my text using my loaded tokenizer but am getting the following error

> `AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'oov_token'`

I included the code below:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Model, Input, Sequential, load_model
import pickle
import h5py

maxlen = 100
tok = open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb')
tokenizer = pickle.load(tok)
tok.close()
model = load_model('weights.h5')

def predict():
    new_text = sequence.pad_sequences((tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(['heyyyy'])), maxlen=maxlen)
    prediction = model.predict(new_text,batch_size=1,verbose=2)
```

The problem occurs on the line `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(['heyyyy'])` and I'm not sure why. Is the problem with pickle? the `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences` works with `'hey'`, `'heyy'`, and `'heyyy'`.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: I updated the post with all the code

Comment: Ah, this might be of interest: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9099

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most probably [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9099):

> You can manually set `tokenizer.oov_token = None` to fix this.
>
> Pickle is not a reliable way to serialize objects since it assumes
>   that the underlying Python code/modules you're importing have not
>   changed. In general, DO NOT use pickled objects with a different
>   version of the library than what was used at pickling time. That's not
>   a Keras issue, it's a generic Python/Pickle issue. In this case
>   there's a simple fix (set the attribute) but in many cases there will
>   not be.